# Js | String split by the first whitespace

Tags: javascript

Im trying to split a user input value by the first space.

Example: User inputs the following command: **/command test command** into a input field.

The code now removes the first charackter in that string which would be: **/**

Now the code should split the remaining input ("command test command") by the first whitespace, so the following would remain:

- command
- test command

My problem is the following: My code splits the command at any whitespace. A example is made here:

```js
$("#execute").click(function() {
  var command = $("#command").val().substr(1);
  var args = command.split(/[ ]+/);
  var commandName = args[0];
  args.shift()
  
 $("#content").text("Command: " + commandName + " Text: " + args);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Berechnen votes</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="command" type="text" value="/command test command">
    <button id="execute">Execute</button>
    <br><br>
    <span id="content"></span>
  </body>

</html>
```

I appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: We can't point the bug in your code if you don't share it.

Comment: Edited the question, didnt work out as i expected it before.

Comment: After extracting the word `command` from the array, the remaining items in the array is the rest, so just join them together again? You could use a more complicated splitting regex, but for trivial things like this, that seems overkill.

Comment: `.indexOf(' ')` will give you the position of the first space, `.substr()` will let you read before/after that point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a regular expression:

```js
let input = " /command test command";
let [, command, args] = input.match(/^\W*(\S+)\s+(.*)$/);

console.log("command:", command);
console.log("args:", args);
```